# What is the dummy variable trap?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, fixed-effects-model

I am currently trying to run a fixed regression. 
The dependent variable is the online rating for a book and one of my control variables is a dummy which describes whether the book is an eBook or a hardcover. 
Stata always omits this dummy. I think this is due to the dummy variable trap, but I don't fully understand what that is and, more importantly, how to fix it.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The dummy should not be omitted altogether, it's just that there should be one dummy for two groups, at least if you include an intercept in the model.

Comment: I tried that now. I added a "ebook dummy" (1 if ebook, 0 if hardcover) and a "hardcover dummy" (1 if hardcover, 0 if ebook). Now Stata omits both dummies. 
Is that what you meant?

Comment: Try fitting the model with just one of these dummies.

Comment: That's what I did initially... Doesn't work :-/

Comment: IMHO the Wikipedia explanation is quite clear; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)#Incorporating_a_dummy_independent  If you include a constant (intercept) term then you must omit one of the dummies.